# SFMC - Use Script to Retrieve List members for * status

Tags: marketing-cloud, list, ssjs

I am attempting to use the subscribers.Retrieve function to retrieve members of a list. However, I am hitting a roadblock with the parameters. I'm looking at member status, but I can't seem to use a wildcard, or more likely I'm using it incorrectly.

`var subs = myList.Subscribers.Retrieve({Property:"Status", SimpleOperator:"equals", Value:/.*/});`

I can do it correctly using a static status, such as

`var subs = myList.Subscribers.Retrieve({Property:"Status", SimpleOperator:"equals", Value:"Active"});`

but retrieving members of all statuses is causing an issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Providing a filter expression is not mandatory. If you want to retrieve all subscribers irrespective of status, then leave the filter out:

```
var subs = myList.Subscribers.Retrieve();
```

Where your need is to retrieve large numbers of subscribers from a list(s), consider using a Query Activity to retrieve your list from the [ListSubscribers Data View](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_listsubscribers/). This will be less complex than API SSJS functions to page through until no more results are available and will run in a fraction of the time of a script:

```
SELECT
    SubscriberKey,
    EmailAddress,
    Status,
    CreatedDate
FROM
    _ListSubscribers WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    ListID = 2323507
```

The ListID can be found on the Properties tab of your list in the Marketing Cloud User Interface.

Comment: Now I seem to be running in to the issue of capping at 2500 subscribers. Is this a timeout type thing or other limitation?

Comment: API Retrieves send back pages of up to 2500 records, so you need to page through the results until all pages have been returned. Before pointing you in in the direction of a solution, it would be good to understand why you're using SSJS to retrieve large numbers of records. What's the use case?

Comment: Ah that makes sense. So we have a list that is being populated via API that we don't control or have access to. I'm attempting to have that list copied into a data extension, but automated rather than manually.

Comment: Far more performant and probably less complicated would be to use a Query Activity for this. What fields are you looking at running into your DE from from the LIst?

Comment: Email Address, Status, Added Date...I was under the impression that you can't query a List in SFMC?

Comment: No. You can query a set of Data Views and feed the results into a Data Extension. You just can't go the other way and feed query results into a list. My problem now is they seem to have removed all the decent documentation from Help. I'll add a query to the above.

Comment: So the query worked perfectly. I have one followup question though - I attempted that exact query a few days ago (without WITH (NOLOCK)) and it returned 0 rows.....does WITH (NOLOCK) do something that would affect that?

Comment: No. It's more through force of habit that I add the clause as it tries to stop creating any locking issues where you stop other processes from using the table/view. I'm not certain it's even paid attention to in a Query Activity, but I put it there anyway. More likely there was some issue with your query, like a typo.

Comment: One tip, if you're not already doing it, is to always run your Query Activities within an Automation as you get far better feedback in terms of error reporting than when you just click on the "Run Once" button for the Query. If your have an error with run once, you just end up with no records in your DE and no feedback.